# Kobotoolbox & Google sheet Sync

Tags: javascript, synchronization, google-sheets-api

I want make sync between KoboToolbox (data collection ) and Google sheet, but the code didn't work: I need the data update automatically, but it doesn't.

[link to my document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jhkzZPplKESIRUkwNyuVm2IChg-vqX-7kjaXtIYVjI8/edit#gid=0)

```js
//See ReadMe file for more information which can be found at 
//https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kobocat-googleapps-scripts

/* Declare global varibles that are used multiple times*/
var app = UiApp.createApplication();//This creates the application which is used for setup
var current_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //This is the current spreadsheet
var checked_URL = ''; //This is a placeholder for the URL of the kobocat form the user has selected during setup

/***** SECTION 1 - Everything from here to the next section is part of the Setup menu item *****/
function setup(){
//This function gets information from the user including authentication token and which form updates this sheet.

  
  var description = app.createLabel('You must get your API Token from your user account by visiting http://kc.kobotoolbox.org/YOUR-USERNAME/api-token', true);
  var grid = app.createGrid(3, 3);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('API Token: '));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('token'));

  // Create a vertical panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();  
  
  // Add the description and grid to the panel
  panel.add(description);
  panel.add(grid);
  
  // Create a button and click handler; pass in the grid object as a callback element and the handler as a click handler
  // Identify the function as the server click handler

  var button = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('saveToken');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  
  // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the application app in the Spreadsheet doc
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  current_sheet.show(app);

}

function saveToken(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  
  //Clear the all properties first
  ScriptProperties.deleteAllProperties();
  
  //Save the token and let the user know by message box
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('token', e.parameter.token);
  Browser.msgBox('Token Saved');
  //Now, get the form list from kobocat and ask the user which form is meant to update this sheet
  setupScriptProperties();//Get the URLs of each of the users forms
  askUser();//Now that the token is saved, ask the user which form is meant to update this sheet
}

function askUser() {
  //Load the script properties into an array to see how many forms there are
  var num_forms = parseInt(ScriptProperties.getProperty('num_forms')) + 1;//we use parseInt to make sure an integer is returned, not a string
  
  //Create a FlexTable to hold values
  var table = app.createFlexTable().setId('table').setBorderWidth(1).setCellPadding(1)
  
  //Set Headers of the table
  table.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Form Name'));
  table.setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel('Update this sheet'));
  
  //Create a server handler that handles the checkbox when it's changed
  var check = app.createServerHandler('check');
  check.addCallbackElement(table);
  
 //The ScriptProperties stores everything as strings. We have to convert true and false strings into boolean properties that can be read by the checkbox
 for(r=0;r<num_forms-1; r++){
    var formname= 'form'+r+'name';//Define the formname to pull from getProperty
    var this_sheet_property_name = 'form'+r+'this_sheet';//Define the property name
    var this_sheet_val = ScriptProperties.getProperty(this_sheet_property_name);
    if(this_sheet_val == 'true') {
      this_sheet_val = Boolean(true);
    }else{
      this_sheet_val = Boolean(false);
    }

    //Set the labels and checkboxes in the grid
    table.setWidget(r+1, 0, app.createLabel(ScriptProperties.getProperty(formname)));
    table.setWidget(r+1,1,app.createCheckBox().addValueChangeHandler(check).setName('check'+r).setValue(this_sheet_val));// create the checkBox once every row if condition is true and give it a name
  }

  // Create a vertical panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  
  // Create a button and click handler that closes the app because the action of checking the box kicks off the check(e) function that saves the scriptproperty
  var button = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('closeApp')
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  // ...and add the table to the panel
  panel.add(table);
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  
  current_sheet.show(app);
}

function check(e) {
 //This function takes the user's input from the form and writes preferences to setProperty
  var num_forms = parseInt(ScriptProperties.getProperty('num_forms'));//we use parseInt to make sure an integer is returned, not a string
  
  for(var n=0; n < num_forms;n++){
    var formname= 'form'+n+'name';//Define the formname to pull from getProperty
    var this_sheet_property_name = 'form'+n+'this_sheet';//Set the property name
    //Set the values of the checked box in the ScriptProperties
    ScriptProperties.setProperty(this_sheet_property_name, e.parameter['check'+n]);
  } 
}

function setupScriptProperties(){
  
  var json_array = getkobocatData('https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms');
  //Get the username from the json_array URL
  var kobocat_users = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/users',getUrlFetchOptions()).getContentText());
  var kobocat_username = kobocat_users[0]["username"];
  
  //Assign the script properties
  
  for (var j=0; j<json_array.length; j++)
  { 
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('form'+j+'name',json_array[j]["id_string"]);//This value saves the name of the form
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('form'+j+'URL', json_array[j]["url"]);//This value saves the URL of the form
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('form'+j+'this_sheet', 'false');//This value will determine if this form is the one that updates the sheet
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('form'+j+'num_responses', 0)//This tracks the number of form responses per form allowing us to know if there has been an update 
  }
  //Save the number of forms
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('num_forms', j);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('kobocat_username', kobocat_username);
  //Logger.log(ScriptProperties.getProperty('num_forms'));
}

function closeApp(){

app.close();
Browser.msgBox("Setup Complete");

}

/***** SECTION 2 - Everything from here to the next section is part of the 'Import Data' menu item *****/
function ImportData(){
//This function imports data from kobocat to the existing spreadsheet

  //First check to see if the setup has been run by evaluating the first form's name. If it's null run setup
  if(ScriptProperties.getProperty('form0name')== null){
    setup();
  }else{  
    //See if an update is needed
    if(UpdateNeeded()){
      //if needed, get the data from kobocat
      
      //Call the function getkobocatData but first, change the URL from /forms/ to /data/
      var form_data_JSON = getkobocatData(checked_URL.replace('/forms/','/data/'));//Note this presently returns all data
      
      //Use the setRowsData function (SECTION 5) to write the data to the sheet
      setRowsData(current_sheet.getActiveSheet(), form_data_JSON);
      Logger.log(form_data_JSON);
      Browser.msgBox('Update Complete');
    }else{
      //Tell the user that the form is up to date
      Browser.msgBox('This sheet is up to date')
    }
  }
}


function UpdateNeeded(){
// Check to see which form has a true value for "this_sheet" property
    var num_forms = parseInt(ScriptProperties.getProperty('num_forms'));//we use parseInt to make sure an integer is returned, not a string
    
    for(var n=0; n < num_forms;n++){
      var formname= 'form'+n+'name';//Define the formname to pull from getProperty
      var this_sheet_property_name = 'form'+n+'this_sheet';//Set the property name
      if(ScriptProperties.getProperty(this_sheet_property_name) =='true'){
        var checked_formname = ScriptProperties.getProperty('form'+n+'name');
        checked_URL = ScriptProperties.getProperty('form'+n+'URL');
      }
    }    
        
    //Connect to kobocat and get the form list
    var list_of_forms_JSON = getkobocatData('https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/forms');
    
    //Match the checked_formname to the form in the list_of_forms_JSON and get the number of submissions
    for (var i=0; i < list_of_forms_JSON.length; i++){
      if(list_of_forms_JSON[i]['id_string'] == checked_formname) {
        var latest_num_of_submissions = list_of_forms_JSON[i]['num_of_submissions'];
      }
    }
    
    //Check to see if number of submissions is different than the number of rows in the spreadsheet
    var lastsheetrow = current_sheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow() - 1; //set the last row of the current sheet (Assuming 1 row header)
    var Update_Needed = true; //assume an update is needed unless the number of rows in the sheet is different from the latest num of submissions 
    
    
    if (latest_num_of_submissions == lastsheetrow) {
      Update_Needed = false;
    }
    
    return Update_Needed;
}

/***** SECTION 3 - Communicating with the kobocat server (used more than once) getkobocatData and Token Authorization Parameters *****/

function getkobocatData(getDataURL){
  //First, we have to translate the 
  var list_of_forms = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getDataURL,getUrlFetchOptions()).getContentText();  //provides a TEXT list of form names and URLs
  var json_array = JSON.parse(list_of_forms); //parse to JSON so we can work with the data in an array
  //Logger.log(json_array);
  return json_array;
    
}

function getUrlFetchOptions() {
//This function returns the Authorization headers with token information to kobocat
  return {
            "headers" : {
                         "Authorization" : "Token " + ScriptProperties.getProperty('token'),
                        }
         };
}

/***** SECTION 4 - Working with JSON object and entering into spreadsheet *****/
//The following Google Developers site was instrumental in writing this code: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading

// setRowsData fills in one row of data per object defined in the objects Array.
// For every Column, it checks if data objects define a value for it.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the Sheet Object where the data will be written
//   - objects: an Array of Objects, each of which contains data for a row
//   - optHeadersRange: a Range of cells where the column headers are defined. This
//     defaults to the entire first row in sheet.
//   - optFirstDataRowIndex: index of the first row where data should be written. This
//     defaults to the row immediately below the headers.
function setRowsData(sheet, objects, optHeadersRange, optFirstDataRowIndex) {
  var headersRange = optHeadersRange || sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var firstDataRowIndex = optFirstDataRowIndex || headersRange.getRowIndex() + 1;
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    var values = []
    for (j = 0; j < headers.length; ++j) {
      var header = headers[j];
      // If the header is non-empty and the object value is 0...
      if ((header.length > 0) && (objects[i][header] == 0)) {
        values.push(0);
      }
      // If the header is empty or the object value is empty...
      else if ((!(header.length > 0)) || (objects[i][header]=='')) {
        values.push('');
      }
      else {
        values.push(objects[i][header]);
      }
    }
    data.push(values);
  }

  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(firstDataRowIndex, headersRange.getColumnIndex(),
                                        objects.length, headers.length);
  destinationRange.setValues(data);
}

/***** SECTION 5 - Setting up custom menu *****/
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Setup",
    functionName : "setup"
  },
  { name : "Import Data",
    functionName : "ImportData"
   }];
  sheet.addMenu("Update from kobocat", entries);
};
```

thank you

Comment: If no one can help, you should try to corner up the issue and write a smaller [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello J. Chomel, How you can help me please

Comment: I know nothing about this stack. Try ask a more specific question after you read [ask]